# SwiftUI how to detect when a view has the focus?

Tags: swiftui

I have two List's in a view and want to be able to determine which list currently has the focus in order to show the correct details of the selected item in the list in a details panel.

The following code never seems to get called, can anyone indicate whether there is another correct way to determine when focus changes.

```
struct StoreList: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var database: Database
    @Binding var selectedStore: Store?

    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selectedStore) {
            ForEach(database.stores, id: \.self) { store in
                StoreRow(store: store).tag(store)
                .focusable(true, onFocusChange:  { isFocused in
                    print("focus changed")
                        if isFocused {
                            self.database.selectedType = .store
                        }
                })
            }
        }
        .focusable(true, onFocusChange: { isFocused in
            print("focus changed")
                if isFocused {
                    self.database.selectedType = .store
                }
        })
    }
}
```

In the meantime I will explore detecting mouse clicks on the Rows since the user would need to click on an item in the list to move the focus.

Currently I am setting the selectedType value when an item changes (i.e. $selectedStore) in the view model (database) but if the user selected the already selected item in the other list then the value does not get updated but the List and list item does get the focus - well the visual colour change indicates it has the focus.

EDIT:
I have also tried processing the onTapGesture callback which works fine except it replaces the List rows default behaviour.  How can I make sure the event is passed through to the List as this might work then.

Comment: `.focusable` (in AppKit it is part of KeyboardUI category) works only on keyboard navigation for views which can become first responder. Mouse click, in general, might not change first responder, by default, or view does not become first responder on mouse click.

Comment: @Asperi thanks, I guess that makes sense - so I wonder what the correct way is to detect when a view becomes the active view.

Comment: As far as I understood your Lists are mutually exclusive, and details are shown either to selection in one List or in another, so the approach can be as cleaning (set to nil) selection of one List when another list item is selected and vice-versa. In SwiftUI we have to operate with states (or model), not views.

Comment: @Asperi one list has parent and the other has children and the detail panel needs to show details of the currently active object (parent or child). So user can select a parent and see a list of children and select a child.  When the parent is selected the parents children show in the child list and the parent details show in the detail panel.  When a child is selected the Childs details show in the details panel.  Now if the user clicks on the parent again the parents details need to show in the details panel. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method of reacting to focus is

```
struct DummyView: View {
    @Environment(\.isFocused) var isFocused

    var body: some View {
        Text("My view")
        .padding()
        .background(isFocused ? Color.orange : Color.black)
    }
}
```

Comment: that environment var does not work at all for me, the color does not change.